# How to create a Dojo onDrop event in Drag and Drop Source

Tags: events, dojo, drag-and-drop

I have a dojo.dnd.Source for a drag and drop and want to fire an event when the user drops an item from a source box to a target box.  Any one have a good example of how to fire this event?

The supporting documentation has not be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, the documentation is massive on this subject.. Seen this: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dnd.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using declarative syntax but for some reason it wouldn't fire when I did a dojo.connect.

```
`<div data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" accept="widget" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <script type="dojo/connect" event="onDrop" args="source, nodes, copy">
     alert('onDrop');
   </script>
</div>`
```

Yes the documentation is massive but I don't think it had a specific example of this. I did see some other posts on stack overflow so you might want to do some more poking around.